# Is there a better way to update same field in multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 10 tables, and i want to update the same field in all of them with the same value. The update takes as condition a field which is primary key in one table, foreign in others and there are some tables where it isnt even a key. For example :

```
  TABLEX               TABLEY                 TABLEZ         

  FIELD1 (PK)          FIELD1(FK)             FIELD1               
  FIELD3               FIELD3                 FIELD3
```

I want to update FIELD3 in all tables with the same value for the same FIELD1. I have been told to use a stored procedure using cursors a for loops to update the tables and after investigating a bit i have read that cursors aint very time efficient. I was wondering if this is the best way or if you know of a better approach. Im fairly new to sql.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the database design if the same field appears in ten different tables?

Comment: Why dont you try with triggers. When you update first table update all the others as well at same time.

Comment: Relational Databases shouldn't ever require this.  The data should only ever appear in one table if the structure has been normalised.  If it has been de-normalised, such as caching results in multiple places, then you'll have to issue 10 UPDATEs.

Comment: @FrankPI & MatBailie: FIELD3 is used to save the data in diferent partitions. Dunno if using  the same field in all the tables is the best design for this but i dont have control over it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need to use cursor loops - a simple SQL UPDATE statement will work just as fine on all 10 tables. However, you do have to issue 10 separate UPDATE statements, there is no way around that.

Note: if you used dynamic SQL, you could end up with a little bit less code but I'd very much recommend against it for a host of reasons: code readability, disrupts built-in SQL object dependency tracking, SQL injection possibilities...)

Comment: I forgot to mention this update is supposed to happen every night.So i guess a stored procedure is a must given i have to schedule it. I could still use the procedure in conjuction with triggers or do the updates as u proposed. Do u think using triggers would be a better approach over your solution? Thx

Comment: My recommendations is to avoid triggers as much as possible, unless it's something very basic e.g. inserting sequences. That's for 2 reasons - the maintainability of code (packages/procedures) as well as the notorious mutating error.